# constexpr user-defined literal: Is it allowed?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to hash my string with user-defined literal prior in compile time

```
constexpr unsigned int const_hash(char const *input) {
    return *input ?
        static_cast<unsigned int>(*input) + 33 * const_hash(input + 1) :
        5381;
}

constexpr unsigned int operator ""_hash (const char *input, size_t) {
    return const_hash(input);
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%i\n", "test"_hash);
    return 0;
}
```

It works in GCC

```
mov esi, 2090770981
mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
xor eax, eax
call printf
```

but not in MSVC

```
push     OFFSET ??_C@_04CEJDCDCH@test?$AA@+1
call     ?const_hash@@YAIPBD@Z
mov      ecx, eax
add      eax, 116   ; 00000074H
shl      ecx, 5
add      eax, ecx
push     eax
push     OFFSET ??_C@_03PELOGHMK@?$CFi?6?$AA@
call     _printf
add      esp, 12              ; 0000000cH
```

so I guess constexpr user-defined literals is an UB/compiler implementation? Is it specified in FDIS?

(Look I know recursive constexpr function is not allowed but I'm using it as an example)

Edit:

Here's a FNV-1 non-recursive one: http://godbolt.org/g/KF9BaE

Here's a DJB2 non-recursive one again: http://godbolt.org/g/7eJmpp

I could force the constant hash behavior by installing a template: 
 http://godbolt.org/g/fsuFS9

but then I will not be allowed to pre-evaluate hash for string literal operator because the string literal in parameter is already decayed to pointer

Comment: "*Look I know recursive constexpr function is not allowed but I'm using it as an example*" Has it occurred to you that maybe that's why it's not working, rather than the fact that you're using a UDL? It seems questionable to use as a test a thing that `constexpr` functions cannot do, UDL or not.

Comment: no i tried various constexpr C++ hash functions, including crc32, fnv1, djb2, recursive and non-recursive ones, all of them shared a similar behavior.

Comment: The constexpr hash function I used here is a djb2 variant.

Comment: Then provide an example that is not recursive.

Comment: Pertinent information goes in the *question*, not the comments below. Feel free to edit your question and add those things to it.

Comment: You don't use the literal in a context that requires a constant expression. If you add `constexpr unsigned hash = "test"_hash;` MSVC17 will compute the value at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Your context does not require constexpr, so it can be done at runtime

```
printf("%i\n", "test"_hash);
```

You should change to

```
constexpr auto test_hash = "test"_hash;
printf("%i\n", test_hash);
```

What you observe is optimization of compiler.